# Create a table with double title

Tags: pdf, latex, tabular

I have this code to create a table, but I want to create a table like the image below. How can I modify the code to create the table?

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
   & AB & A & B & O \\ \hline
AB & 0  & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \hline
A  & 1  & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
B  & 1  & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ \hline
O  & 3  & 3 & 3 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: Table]

Comment: Can you please make a [mre]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully easy:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cc|c|c|c|c|}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Classified As} \\
 &                       & AB & A & B & O \\ \cline{2-6}
\multirow{4}{11mm}{True Blood Type} %
 & AB                    & 0  & 1 & 1 & 2 \\ \cline{2-6}
 & A                     & 1  & 0 & 2 & 2 \\ \cline{2-6}
 & B                     & 1  & 2 & 0 & 2 \\ \cline{2-6}
 & O                     & 3  & 3 & 3 & 0 \\ \cline{2-6}
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The above [**MWE**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) outputs the following table:

[image: Screenshot of output]

This first sketch can then be improved aesthetically in several ways!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}%
  \begin{tabular}{c c *{4}{| c} |}
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Classified As} \\
    &    & AB & A & B & O \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & AB & 0  & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    \multirow{2}*{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
        True \\ Blood \\ Type
      \end{tabular}} & A  & 1  & 0 & 2 & 2 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & B  & 1  & 2 & 0 & 2 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    & O  & 3  & 3 & 3 & 0 \\
    \cline{2-6}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```